# User Defined aggfunc DataFrame Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i need to replace the aggfunc in my dataframe pivot as i cannot simply sum the daily returns to provide a monthly return

```
df2=df2.pivot_table(index='EOM',columns='factor',values='return',aggfunc= 
[np.sum])
```

I need to use something like this instead

```
np.exp(np.log1p(df['return']).cumsum()-1)
```

What is the best way to replace this aggfunc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

```
my_aggfunc = lambda x: np.exp(np.log1p(x).cumsum()-1)

df2=df2.pivot_table(index='EOM',columns='factor',values='return',aggfunc= 
my_aggfunc)
```

alternatively, you can define a function with `def my_aggfunc(x):`...etc

Comment: seems to be returning some strange resuls

Comment: each cell is now a list of numbers instead of just 1...any ideas?

Comment: typically an aggegation function takes an array and returns a single value. For example  `np.sum()` returns a single value. I now see that the function that you suggest (i.e.`my_aggfunc`) returns an array. Im not quite sure what you want to do with your custom aggreagtion, but you must edit in such a way that it returns one value for an arrag of `df2['return']`. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it does thanks...the agg function is being used as part of a pivot table in a dataframe...any idea how i can change it this works? it seems abit tricky

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I can see you want to use it in a pivot table. I meant what do you expect the function to do? I am gonna take a guess and assume that you want a `sum` rather than a `cumsum` in the custom aggregation function. `my_aggfunc = lambda x: np.exp(np.log1p(x).sum()-1)`. Is the numbers from that what you were expecting?